# Prove two non-collinear vectors span $\Bbb{R}^2$

Tags: linear-algebra

How do we prove this in a non circular way (aka not just reciting some definitions of span and linear dependence)?

For example, if there is some way to show algebraically, starting with the property of two non-collinear vectors $v_1$ and $v_2$:

$v_1 \neq c* v_2$

That:

$c_1 * v_1 + c_2 * v_2 = d_1 * e_1 + d_2 * e_2$

Where $e_1$ and $e_2$ are the standard basis vectors, and $c$ and $d$ are coefficients.

Answer (score 3):

If there were a nontrivial relation between $v_1= (x_1, y_1)^T$ and $v_2= (x_2,y_2)^T$, then there would be $a,b$, not both zero, so that
$$
a \begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ y_1 \end{pmatrix} + b \begin{pmatrix} x_2 \\ y_2 \end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}
$$
Without loss of generality, assume $a \neq 0$. Then we have
$$
\begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ y_1 \end{pmatrix}= -\dfrac{b}{a}\begin{pmatrix} x_2 \\ y_2 \end{pmatrix}
$$
Then, of course,
$$
\begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ y_1 \end{pmatrix}= c\begin{pmatrix} x_2 \\ y_2 \end{pmatrix}
$$
where $c= -b/a$, a contradiction.

Not sure if this is quite what you had hoped for, as it does use the definition of dependence - which most any argument will in some sense - but does rest on the fact that $v_1 \neq c v_2$ for any $c \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Can you please directly incorporate usage of the definition of span into this answer.

Comment: It seems like you're arguing that iff the two vectors are linearly independent, they will span R^2, and then you show that based on the definition of linear independence the vectors cannot be collinear. It would be easier to see exactly what you mean if you wrote something like that in the answer.

Comment: @user3180 There is no need. You have two linearly independent vectors so they must span a two dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$, i.e. all of $\mathbb{R}^2$. Otherwise, if you want to show span more directly, $x_1,x_2,y_1,y_2$ are fixed. Suppose you want the vector $v=(n,m)^T$, then expanding the first equation above with $v$ instead of the 0 vector and relating components, you have a linear system of 2 unknowns and 2 equations, which I'm sure you can handle solving.

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Solve%5Ba+x1+%2B+b+x2%3D%3D+n%26%26+a+y1+%2B+b+y2%3D%3D+m%2C%7Ba%2Cb%7D%5D

Comment: Why are you allowed to do the WLOG step? Why do the steps still hold even if a = 0?

Comment: NVM, i see, it's because if a was 0, you could just switch the coefficient to -a/b... and only a or b can be 0

Comment: What is the contradiction exactly? Why can't -b/a = c?

Comment: @user3180 Because then the vectors are parallel. Remember they are parallel if $v_1= c v_2$ for some choice of $c$. You are showing that in this case, you would choose $c= -b/a$.

Comment: Here you start by saying v1 and v2 are linearly independent implies they *are* collinear. This is the claim made for proof by contradiction. There are no logical contradictions made in your proof, linear independence is not shown to imply non-collinearity... all the algebra you made *does* allow -b/a = c... which means linearly independent *can* allow for collinearity

Comment: What is the exact proposition you are making for proof my contradiction?

Comment: @user3180 Two vectors are linearly independent by definition if and only if you can write $av_1+bv_2=0$, then $a=b=0$. I show that if you had such an expression that it is equivalent to $v_1= c v_2$, where $c= -b_a$. Then if the vectors are not a parallel, they are linearly independent.

Answer (score 1):

Let $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$ be noncollinear.  WLOG assume $c\neq 0$.  Then $(a,b)-\frac{a}{c}(c,d)=(0,b-\frac{ad}{c})$. Due to noncollionarity, that vector is a scalar multiple of $(0,1)$.  At least one of $b$ and $d$ must also be nonzero by noncollinearity, which means we can get a scalar multiple of $(1,0)$ too.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this further - what is it you're describing with the (a,b) - a/c ... equation?

Answer (score 0):

Let $v = (a, b)$ and $w = (c, d)$ be two non-collinear vectors in $\mathbb R^2$. Let $z = (x, y) \in \mathbb R^2$. If you want to show $z \in \text{span}\{v, w\}$ then you want to show there exists a linear combination $\lambda v + \mu w = z$. This is a linear system
$$ \left(\begin{array}{cc} a & c \\ b & d \\ \end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c} \lambda \\ \mu \\ \end{array}\right) = \left(\begin{array}{c} x \\ y \\ \end{array}\right) $$
and so can be solved for all $z \in \mathbb R^2$ iff $ad - bc \neq 0$, i.e. the determinant is nonzero.

We have three cases to consider, since $a = b = 0$ is impossible.

(1) $a, b \neq 0$. Then 
$$ ad - bc = a\left(\frac{d}{b}b\right) - b\left(\frac{c}{a}a\right) = ab\left(\frac{d}{b} - \frac{c}{a}\right) \neq 0$$
since $\frac{d}{b} = \frac{c}{a} = \kappa$ implies $(c, d) = \kappa(a, b)$, i.e. $v, w$ are collinear.

(2) $a \neq 0$, $b = 0$. Then $d \neq 0$, otherwise $v = (a, 0)$ and $w = (c, 0)$ which are clearly collinear. So 
$$ ad - bc = ad \neq 0.$$

(3) $b \neq 0$, $a = 0$. Same as (2); you know $c \neq 0$ so 
$$ ad - bc = -bc \neq 0.$$

In all three cases the determinant is nonzero, which shows $v, w$ span $\mathbb R^2$; every $z \in \mathbb R^2$ can be expressed as a linear combination of $v, w$. (Alternatively, that the matrix has nonzero determinant means it is invertible, in particular surjective.)